# pandas - function of sort_remaining parameter in sort_index()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm unclear on how the `sort_remaining` parameter in `sort_index()` works.

In the code below, I believe that the two last `print` outputs should be different. The last output should keep the `'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'...` order from the `arrays` original variable.

[According to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), `sort_remaining` works as follows:

> if true and sorting by level and index is multilevel, sort by other levels too (in order) after sorting by specified level

But `sort_index()` seems to disregard this parameter.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [np.array(['baz', 'baz', 'qux', 'qux', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo']),
          np.array(['two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'])]

s = abs(pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=arrays))

print(s)
>   baz  two    1.184898
>        one    0.277570
>   qux  two    0.904124
>        one    0.930612
>   bar  two    0.952764
>        one    0.025261
>   foo  two    0.084330
>        one    2.842760
>   dtype: float64

print(s.sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=True))
>   bar  one    0.025261
>        two    0.952764
>   baz  one    0.277570
>        two    1.184898
>   foo  one    2.842760
>        two    0.084330
>   qux  one    0.930612
>        two    0.904124
>   dtype: float64

print(s.sort_index(level=0, sort_remaining=False))
>   bar  one    0.025261
>        two    0.952764
>   baz  one    0.277570
>        two    1.184898
>   foo  one    2.842760
>        two    0.084330
>   qux  one    0.930612
>        two    0.904124
>   dtype: float64
```

is my dataframe not multi-indexed enough for `sort_remaining` to have an effect?

Comment: Yes that seems inconsistent. `sort_remaining` is respected if you do `s.sort_index(level=1, sort_remaining=True/False)`